# JSP Simple IF statement

Tags: java, jsp, if-statement

so my aim is to make a IF statement determine what the value of 'pbutton' and 'value is.

I have a html page that has two lists boxes, one for PropertyID and another for Location which will look in a database for that value.

ccode and ccode1 are the list boxes from html page.

This is my code for .jsp page

```
    String pbutton=request.getParameter("ccode");

if (pbutton = 0); {
pbutton=request.getParameter("ccode1");
value = Property;
else {
pbutton=request.getParameter("ccode");
value = ID;
}
}
```

However, it doesnt like it, giving me this error....

```
    An error occurred at line: 75 in the jsp file: /Assignment/find.jsp
Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to boolean
72: 
73: String pbutton=request.getParameter("ccode");
74: 
75: if (pbutton = 0); {
76: pbutton=request.getParameter("ccode1");
77: value = Property;
78: else {
```

Help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (pbutton = 0); {
```

Here are three major mistakes. You're assigning an `int` value of `0` to a `String` variable and then checking if it is `true` or `false`. The `=` is an assignment operator, while you actually wanted to use `==` which is the equality operator which returns `true` or `false`. But this is not going to work as well because you're basically comparing a `String` with an `int`. Also, that semicolon doesn't belong there, it won't enter the statement block.

To check whether the `String` value equals to `"0"`, you need this instead:

```
if ("0".equals(pbutton)) {
```

This is rather trivial and basic Java and has got nothing to do with JSP. Writing Java code in JSP files instead of normal Java classes doesn't make it a JSP problem. I'd suggest to stop with whatever you're doing now and invest some time in learning Java properly. Start with [Oracle's own basic Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/). Once having a proper grasp on Java basics, you can continue your work.

Answer (score 0):

== is for comparing and = is for assignment. HOWEVER when comparing strings you must use .equals in java, since == compares objects.